# Decompressing zip file with miniz exits with status -1 (TINFL_STATUS_FAILED)

Tags: c, unzip, zip, inflate

I need to use the miniz library for decompressing some zip files in my project. The problem is that the function

`tinfl_decompress`

always exits with status `TINFL_STATUS_FAILED`.

I have done some debugging and found out the offending lines of code in miniz.c:

line 1452:

```
counter = (((r->m_zhdr0 * 256 + r->m_zhdr1) % 31 != 0) || (r->m_zhdr1 & 32) || ((r->m_zhdr0 & 15) != 8));
```

counter is set to 1;

line 1453:

```
if (!(decomp_flags & TINFL_FLAG_USING_NON_WRAPPING_OUTPUT_BUF)) counter |= (((1U << (8U + (r->m_zhdr0 >> 4))) > 32768U) || ((out_buf_size_mask + 1) < (size_t)(1U << (8U + (r->m_zhdr0 >> 4)))));
```

`(((1U << (8U + (r->m_zhdr0 >> 4))) > 32768U) || ((out_buf_size_mask + 1) < (size_t)(1U << (8U + (r->m_zhdr0 >> 4)))))` evaluates to false; however since counter is set to 1, counter remains equal to 1.

line 1454:

```
if (counter) { TINFL_CR_RETURN_FOREVER(36, TINFL_STATUS_FAILED); }
```

since the counter value is 1 the macro TINFL_CR_RETURN_FOREVER is called. Such macro jumps to the label `common_exit`.

Apart from inside my project, I have tested the miniz library with the examples provided with the libary. Specifically, I have tried to decompress both my own personal zip archives as well as the one generated by the example2 included with the miniz library with example5.

Issuing the folling command at the command prompt

```
example5.exe d __mz_example2_test__.zip __mz_example2_test__.decompress
```

generates the following output:

```
miniz.c example5 (demonstrates tinfl/tdefl)
Mode: d, Level: 9
Input File: "__mz_example2_test__.zip"
Output File: "__mz_example2_test__.decompress"
Input file size: 33768
tinfl_decompress() failed with status -1!
```

How can I fix this? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The problem is that a [zip file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_%28file_format%29) is an *archive* where each file in the archive is compressed (most commonly with [deflate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEFLATE)). However, the zip file itself is *not* compressed. To read a zip *archive* you need some other library that can handle it.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg But most of examples coming with miniz show how to decompress zip files whose filename is passed as a parameter.

Comment: If you look at [example 5](https://code.google.com/p/miniz/source/browse/trunk/example5.c) again, you will see early in the file `#define MINIZ_NO_ARCHIVE_APIS` which means that the library won't have the archive functions needed for zip files. The example if for using the low-level *compression* functions, not the archive functions (which is [example 2](https://code.google.com/p/miniz/source/browse/trunk/example2.c)).

Answer (score 1):

Line 1452 is looking for a zlib header.  The zlib format is not the zip format.  You would need to write your own zip format decoder and then use miniz in a raw inflate mode which does not look for a zlib header but instead decodes raw deflate data at the location you found by decoding the zip headers.

Or you could just use [libzip](http://www.nih.at/libzip/), which does all that for you.

Comment: Can also recommend [libarchive](http://www.libarchive.org/) if the most recent version of libzip is not available for your platform/distrobution. Pre-1.0 version of libzip contains a security issue which is addressed in recent versions.